# How to create dictionary from hierarchical relations from spark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have following spark data frame

```
schema = 'EMPLOYEE_NUMBER int, MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER int'
employees = spark.createDataFrame(
[[801,None], 
[1016,801], 
[1003,801], 
[1019,801], 
[1010,1003], 
[1004,1003], 
[1001,1003],
[1012,1004], 
[1002,1004], 
[1015,1004], 
[1008,1019], 
[1006,1019], 
[1014,1019],
[1011,1019]], schema=schema)
```

I want to create dictionary from above data frame like `{801:[1003,1019,1016], 1019:[1014,1011,1008,1006], 1003:[1010,1001,1004]}` can I build dictionary like this from data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collect_list in group all the employees under `MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER` & then use `collect` & `asDict` in conjunction with `map` to transform the resultant into a dictionary

#### Data Preparation

```
schema = 'EMPLOYEE_NUMBER int, MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER int'

employees = sql.createDataFrame(
[[801,None], 
[1016,801], 
[1003,801], 
[1019,801], 
[1010,1003], 
[1004,1003], 
[1001,1003],
[1012,1004], 
[1002,1004], 
[1015,1004], 
[1008,1019], 
[1006,1019], 
[1014,1019],
[1011,1019]], schema=schema)
```

#### Collect List

```
employees_agg = employees.groupBy('MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER')\
                         .agg(F.collect_list(F.col('EMPLOYEE_NUMBER')).alias('EMPLOYEES'))\
                         .filter(F.col('MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER').isNotNull())


employees_agg.show()

+-----------------------+--------------------+
|MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER|           EMPLOYEES|
+-----------------------+--------------------+
|                   1019|[1008, 1006, 1014...|
|                   1003|  [1010, 1004, 1001]|
|                    801|  [1016, 1003, 1019]|
|                   1004|  [1012, 1002, 1015]|
+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

#### Transform

```
final_dict = {
        row['MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER']: row['EMPLOYEES'] 
            for row in  map(lambda row: row.asDict(), employees_agg.collect())
}


pprint(final_dict)

{
 801: [1016, 1003, 1019],
 1003: [1010, 1004, 1001],
 1004: [1012, 1002, 1015],
 1019: [1008, 1006, 1014, 1011]
}
```

Comment: can we apply some conditions to collect employee ex. if their department is different then add to the list else do not add into the dict
cond like ``` if dept_mngr != dept_emp then add to dict```  something like this

Comment: Yes , this is viable. Add in the dept information and you ll be able to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
datas = employees.groupBy('MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER').agg(collect_set(col('EMPLOYEE_NUMBER')).alias('values')).collect()

ur_dict = {}
for item in datas:
    ur_dict[item['MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER']] = item['values']

print(ur_dict)
# {1019: [1014, 1011, 1008, 1006], None: [801], 1003: [1004, 1001, 1010], 801: [1003, 1019, 1016], 1004: [1002, 1015, 1012]}
```